# C# Linq SQL shows the query as page content

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, model-view-controller

I am learning coding in C# for web applications and i am using MVC to do this.
So far I succeeded in querying the MSSQL database and now I am trying to get this done with Linq. It works but it also shows me the query which is unwanted when it comes to your final result.

This is my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Linqget(string key)
{
    var thelist = (from thenameofthequery in DeDB.whitelists where thenameofthequery.apikey == key select thenameofthequery).ToList();
    return View(thelist);
}
```

This is my view:

```
@Model Linqget
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Linqget";
}

@foreach (var thelist in Model)
{
<div>@thelist.ip</div>
}
```

When I run this and give the correct key in the GET it returns the database records but also (even without the get parameter) the following SQL query:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id], [Extent1].[ip] AS [ip], [Extent1].[apikey] AS [apikey] FROM [dbo].[whitelist] AS [Extent1] WHERE ([Extent1].[apikey] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[apikey] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)) Linqget
```

When I apply a .tolist to "thelist" it returns

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FSAPI.Models.whitelist] Linqget
```

How can I get rid of this echo?

Comment: You should define the model as the list you'll get `@Model List<FSAPI.Models.whitelist>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model declaration is wrong. This results in `.ToString()` being called on your object.

Instead of:

```
@model Linqget
```

Use something like:

```
@model List<Whitelist>
```

Replace `Whitelist` with proper object type of your entity.

Comment: Instead of list I renamed Model to model and used IEnumerable<modelpath>. Thank you and juharr for pointing me into the right direction